# How to keep the 2 latest tags in gitlab and remove the oldest?

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I have the list of tags from gitlab with this commande line **git tag -l**.

Input :

```
echo listTags = $(git tag -l)
listTags= v0.0.1 v0.0.2 v0.1.0 v0.1.0-1  v0.1.0-2  v0.1.0-3  v0.1.0-4  v0.1.0-5

for tag in 'git tag -l'
do
    git tag -d $tag
    git push -v origin :refs/tags/$tag
done
```

I want to remove all the oldest pre-release version and keep the 2 latest

Output:

```
echo listTags = $(git tag -l)
listTags= v0.0.1 v0.0.2 v0.1.0 v0.1.0-4  v0.1.0-5
```

how can i resolve this problem with script shell?

Comment: I assume what you want is a script that follows certain rules to select which tags to delete according to some rule, based on what tags it sees exist. And I think from your example, that the rule is more complicated than what your text explanation seems to suggest - i.e. I think you're looking for something more complex than Nir Gabay's answer.  In that case, I think we need a more clear explanation of what the rule is. Also, I strongly suspect this goes beyond what shell script alone can do; perl is likely a better idea.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger : Exactly, i'm looking to run script in order to delete automatically the unused pre-release tags from my repo gitlab and we must keep the newest pre-release also without deleting the release versions. I think the answer of Nir Gabay, it will delete the release and pre-release versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git tag -l | sort -V |tail -2
```

This command gives you the newest 2 tags

delete all tags execpt the result from that command

Comment: Sorry, this answer can not resolve my problem. Because, there is a probability of deleting the release and pre-release versions. I'm looking only to remove the pre-release versions.

Comment: git tag -l | sort -V |grep "-" |tail -2

Comment: git tag -l | sort -V |grep "-" |tail -2

             Addind grep "-" to the command line which means 
the script will take the newest 2 tags form all tags that have Hyphen in it .
From your example i can see that  only the pre-release has Hyphen so this can work for you

Comment: and you can use the same script without the tail -2 , for the list of all tags that have Hyphen  in it .